# Do I need indexes on ORDER BY columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

We have a query which goes like this:

```
select *
  from foo
 where some_fk_id = <value>
   and modified_date > 'date1'
   and modified_date < 'date2'
 order by modified_date desc;
```

Do I need to create a composite index for `some_fk_id` and `modified_date` in the above scenario?

Comment: The * in your select will reduce the value of having an index, as your query will still need to perform a Key Lookup to get the rest of the values. But it should still be faster with an index. It would be best to explicitly list the columns you want to return, and also list them in an INCLUDE clause when creating the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* a composite index, but satisfying the `some_fk_id` and `modified_date` where clause could be done with indexes alone (i.e. very quickly) if you do.

The best thing to do is to see the query plan and to profile.

You can see the query plan using `EXPLAIN`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo WHERE some_fk_id=1 AND modified_date > 'date1' AND modified_date < 'date2' ORDER BY modified_date DESC;
```

Try it both with and without a composite index and see what plan it comes up with. The worst possible thing that can happen is a `filesort`--try to avoid those if you need to be speedy.

Most importantly, run time trials with the queries, data, and hardware you will actually use. It may be in your particular case that the space taken up by a composite index will slow you down more than just searching through the entries. For example, if some_fk_id has very high selectivity in the table, the second-level index may not be necessary.

Comment: It was doing a filesort, how do I avoid this for the above command? I will try with the index and update you

Answer (score 0):

Not for the ORDER BY - that's applied to the result set *after* the rows are selected. You might want to consider one if you select based on modified_date on a regular basis.

BTW, your supplied statement selects on modified_date > two distinct values. Was that supposed to be one '>' and one '<'?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data, but an index on modified_date would probably be good for both the where and the order by.

If the foreign key conditions only give you a few rows it will be cheap to order the rows by date any way.